# SQL Server Query on grouped records with having at least one date lesser than current date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below table sample: Id 1,2,3 are connected and 4,5 are connected. Now need a sql query which will get records whose created date is lesser than today for atleast one grouped record.

| Id | GroupId | CreatedDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-06-26 10:51:30 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-06-27 10:51:30 |
| 3 | 1 | 2022-06-27 10:51:30 |
| 4 | 2 | 2022-06-27 10:51:30 |
| 5 | 2 | 2022-06-27 10:51:30 |

output: Id's 1,2,3
4,5 will not be in output because both are grouped and date is not lesser than today.

Comment: Use a CTE/derived table with a windowed `MIN` and then filter on that column. Use a correlated `EXISTS`. If you *just* want the `ID`, use a `HAVING`. There are several options. What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: i haven't tried cte, wanted to do in where condition only, could you please help.

Comment: *"wanted to do in where condition only"* The *only* one that can do that is an `EXISTS`.

Comment: can you give a sample with exists?

Comment: [EXISTS (Transact SQL) - Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#examples).

Answer (score 0):

May be this option will suit you:

```
select t1.* from tbl t1 inner join (
    select distinct GroupId from tbl where CreatedDate<'2022-06-27 10:51:30'
) t2 on t2.GroupId=t1.GroupId
```

Comment: Need to add one more condition in the above query: GroupId count should be greater than one.